# How can I use Meteor callbacks with Jquery to automatically scroll to the bottom of a div every time its contents re-render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm building a basic real-time messaging app in Meteor and currently every time a message is created it is appended to the list of messages on the page & everything is working correctly. However once the contents of the messagesList div overflow (I've set it to scroll) I can no longer see the latest messages without scrolling down manually each time.

What is the 'Meteor way' of using callbacks to skip to the bottom automatically (e.g. with Jquery scrolltop) every time the messages list rerenders? I had a go at it in the messages list template helpers but I'm not getting a value returned on scrollTop and I can't figure out if it's my selectors or something to do with Meteor, i.e. where I am putting the code. So I'd really appreciate some pointers.

Here's what I have:

messagesList.html

```
<template name="messagesList">
  <div class="pure-g-r content" id="layout"> 
    <div class="pure-u-1" id="list">
      {{#each messages}}
          {{> messageItem}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

messagesList.js:

```
Template.messagesList.helpers({
  messages: function() {
    return Messages.find();
  }
});

Template.messagesList.rendered = function () {
  console.log("scrolltop is " + $('#list').scrollTop);
  // $('#list').scrollTop( $('#list').height() )
};
```

messageItem.html:

```
<template name="messageItem">
  <div class="email-item email-item pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-3-4">
      <p>
        <strong>{{sentBy}}</strong><br>
        {{msgText}}
      </p>        
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

MessageSubmit.html:

```
<template name="messageSubmit">
  <form class="pure-form">
    <input type="text" name="msg" class="pure-input-rounded">
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button">Speak!</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

messageSubmit.js:

```
Template.messageSubmit.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('new comment created')

    var user = Meteor.user(); 

    var message = {
      msgText: $(e.target).find('[name=msg]').val(),
      sentBy: user.profile.name,
      userId: user._id
    }
    message._id = Messages.insert(message);
    $('.pure-input-rounded').val("");
  }
});
```

main.css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#layout {
  max-height: 60%;
  left: 20px;
  top: 60px;
  position: relative;   
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em !important;
}

.pure-form {    
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a particularly meteor way of doing this, but with this minor fix to your code it should work:

```
Template.messagesList.rendered = function () {
  console.log("scrolltop is " + $('#list').scrollTop());
  $('#list').scrollTop( $('#list').prop("scrollHeight") );
};
```

Comment: thanks so much for the answer & the code clean up... I tried it and it's still returning a value of 0 no matter how far down I have scrolled, and the scroll is not triggering. I wonder if it's something to do with the fact I am calling this in my messagesList rendered function... as the new message itself sits in messageItem.html & the event handlers for a new msg are in messageSubmit.js. Do I need to call this code or some variant of it in messageSubmit.js?

Comment: Can you show us your css? Is your #list really set to overflow and is it the list you want to scroll, or do you want to scroll #layout or perhaps even the document body itself?

Comment: I added my CSS. I want to scroll down within #list without moving the rest of the page so that you always see the latest message without manually scrolling. I deployed to http://supmobile.meteor.com, if you get a chance to take a look. Really appreciate the help

Comment: I looked at it. You #list is not the problem. The #list div is very high, but #layout is not, it's capped at 60%. You can either start scrolling the #layout, or limit the height of #list.

Comment: doh! You're absolutely right, I confused myself and missed the obvious solution. Switched to scrolling layout and now it works fine. Thanks Christian

Comment: With the Meteor 0.8+ rendering engine, this approach will probably need to go on the `messagesItem` callback for it to work.