# When the page loads scroll down (not so simple) : Meteor JS

Tags: meteor

I have chat app, and if you use `Slack` you know that when you enter to the room, you will automatically find yourself at the bottom of your chat room.
So I decided to do this and what I have

```
Template.room.onCreated(function() {
  console.log($(document).height(),$(window).height());
  $('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height()-$(window).height());
});
```

it output `437` , `437`

**BUT** when I do this in console:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() + 64}, "fast");
```

it outputs `2000`,`437` , and that means that my messages is not loaded fully in my template. (If someone want more code, just ask.)

Any idea how to build this ?

**EDIT:**

This part of template.html

```
<div class="messages-wrap"> 
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"> 

                    {{#if haseMoreMessages}}
                        <div class="loadmore text-center" id="incLimit">Load More</div>
                    {{/if}}
                    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady }}
                        {{#each messages}}
                            {{> message}}
                        {{/each}}
                    {{/if}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And template.js (part of it)

```
Template.room.onRendered(function() {
  Session.setDefault('messageLimit', 200);
});

    Template.room.onCreated(function() {
      var self = this;
      self.autorun(function() {
    if (self.subscriptionsReady()) {
          Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
            $('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height() - $(window).height());
          });
        }
      });

    });

    Template.room.events({
      'click #incLimit' : function(e,template){
        Session.set('messageLimit',Session.get('messageLimit') + 100);
      }
    });
    Template.room.helpers({
      messages: function(){
          return Messages.find({},{sort:{createdAt:1}});
      },
       haseMoreMessages:function(){
        if (Session.get('messageLimit') > Messages.find().count()) return false;
        return true;
       },
    });
```

Comment: have you tried `onRendered` instead of `onCreated`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Meteor callbacks with Jquery to automatically scroll to the bottom of a div every time its contents re-render?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410562/how-can-i-use-meteor-callbacks-with-jquery-to-automatically-scroll-to-the-bottom)

Comment: yep, and I read this answer (yours) and this doesn't help

Comment: weird; that must have changed since then. I can reproduce your issue now but don't yet have a clue.

Comment: I think this won't work. If you read the comment by Andrew it seems that in more recent version of meteor you can't do this on the parent anymore. You'll need to do it on the items in whatever list you have that fill the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one very frustrating aspect of Blaze. Try this, though:

```
Template.room.onRendered(function () {
  var template = this;

  this.autorun(function () {
    if (template.subscriptionsReady()) {
      Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
        $('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height() - $(window).height());
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This waits till all the template subscriptions are ready first, and then waits till any computations are fully complete (`Tracker.afterFlush`), and *then* executes the scroll. `Tracker.afterFlush` is usually necessary if your template has `{{#if}}` blocks that depend on other things before they get evaluated and rendered.

UPDATE:

Without seeing all your code and knowing why or when you want to scroll to the top, it's hard to say what you're aiming for. But see the Meteorpad link below for a working version of what you were trying to do with the message limits (I'm only incrementing the limit by 1 since there are 3 messages).

[Meteorpad Link](http://meteorpad.com/pad/taQthoMx2hHNRxT4s/loadmore)

A few things you should note:

- Set default variables and subscribe to things in `Template.x.onCreated`, not `Template.x.onRendered`.
- You forgot to actually subscribe to your collection.
- Limit messages on the server side, in the `Meteor.publish` callback.

Comment: works great, but I realy don't understand how ? Because `subscriptionsReady()` - `true` when first element from mongo come to the template, so `afterFlush` wait for all documents from mongo ? or it's wrong way

Comment: and I have problem with it, in my template I have `SHOW MORE` button, when u click on it's, show more messages, and when I click on it, my template `scrolltop` , how to avoid this ?

Comment: Most likely on the first run, `subscriptionsReady()` returns `false`, but since that method is reactive, it will trigger the autorun and run again once it becomes `true`. You may not need the `Tracker.afterFlush`, I usually just put that in there to make sure the template is fully rendered. As to your second question, you'd have to edit your post and share the 'show more' code.

Comment: @ffxsamyesterday so, can u help me ?

Comment: @ffxsamyesterday no no :) , I have working chat with `show more` button that shows more messages , and all work ok ! BUT when I click on `show more` button my window scroll to the bootom of the page , like when I first come to this chat room, or refresh the page

Comment: I did notice a slight jump when I clicked, too. But I think it's because the template shrinks for a quick moment because of the `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}` being false. And so nothing is shown (or in the case of the code I posted, it just says "Loading"). Since there's no content, the page shrinks for a second, and then the content comes back and the scroll position has changed.

Comment: The `onRendered` is definitely not being called a second time when you click on "Show More," if that's what you're worried about. `onRendered` is only called once when the template is rendered.

Comment: @ffxsamyesterda but when I click on `show more` code in your answer reruns

Comment: Sorry.. I'm not really clear on what the issue is. I can't replicate any kind of scrolling.

Comment: u must have sckrolling when u refresh the page u scroll to the bottom of the page , u help me with that in your answer, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Different Approach via **tracking** of **Template helpers**:

I took advantage of the Template helper, as it **already tracks reactively all changes (and new) messages**. Hence, there you can place your scroll-down command.

```
Template.room.helpers({
  messages: function(){
      //put your scroll-up command here
      //as this helper is keeping track on changes already
      $('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height() - $(window).height());
      return Messages.find({},{sort:{createdAt:1}});
  },
   haseMoreMessages:function(){
    if (Session.get('messageLimit') > Messages.find().count()) return false;
    return true;
   },
});
```

Hence, you save the resources to have an additional tracker observing the collection (you would be *double-tracking* the same collection).